# a program to check if a reversed string is a palindrome or not using Stack Machine in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, stack

can u help me to solve the following

am trying to get a string input from user, then push the string into the StackMachine so as to check the validity of the string. if the String passes the rules defined, the output string from the StackMachine is to be checked if its a palindrome or not ..this is what i have tried so far

***note*** you can only use the function in the StackMachine class and not another method to determine the validity of the string. The condition to accept a string is that you have read all the input string and the stack is empty

````
    ```

class StackMachine(object):
SMRules = {}   # dictionary of SM rules
def __init__(self):
    self.Stack = ['S']          # populate stack with initial 'S'
    self.size = 1               # set size of stack to 1
    self.SMRules = {}           # Place rules here
    
def pop(self):
    if len(self.Stack) <1:
        pass
    else:
        self.Stack.pop(0)
        self.size-= 1           # reduce stack size by 1
    return

def peek(self):
    ss = ""
    if len(self.Stack) < 1:
        return ""
    else:
        ss = self.Stack
        return ss[0]

def stackIsEmpty(self):
    if len(self.Stack) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def push(self,str):
    sStr = str[::-1] # slicing 
    for chr in sStr:
        self.Stack.insert(0,chr)    # push string onto top of stack
    self.size = len(self.Stack)
    return
    
def printStack(self):
    print("Stack: [",end='')
    for item in self.Stack:
        print(item,end='')
    print("]")
    return
    
def printRules(self):
    print("SM Rules:")
    rn = 1
    for key, value in self.SMRules.items():
        print("Rule",rn,"%4s" % key,"|", value) 
        rn += 1         
    return
def main():
    Stk = StackMachine()
    text =str(input('Please enter the string: '))
    for character in text:
        Stk.push(character)
        reversed_text = ''
        while not Stk.stackIsEmpty():
            reversed_text = reversed_text + Stk.pop()
            if text == reversed_text:
                print('The string is a palindrome.')
            else:
                print('The string is not a palindrome.')
                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    main()
````

````
Am getting the following Error and i dont know how to solve it

        ```

      File "C:\Users\user\Stack-Machine\StackMachine.py", line 91, in main
        reversed_text = reversed_text + Stk.pop()
    
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str`enter code here`
````

my question is
1.how do I solve the error?
2.how to print string chracter by character from the stackMachine
3.successfully check if the processed string from the Stack Machine is a palindrome or not

Answer (score 0):

As defined, `StackMachine.pop()` returns `None`.

When you do `reversed_text + Stk.pop()`, even though `reversed_text` is a string, `Stk.pop()` is `None`, which causes the `TypeError` you are seeing.

Why do you need to use the so called `StackMachine` class to check if a string is a palindrome? There are simpler ways to check if a string is a palindrome.

If all you want to do is get a string input and determine whether it's a palindrome, you can do so like this:

```
text = input()
isPalindrome = text == text[::-1]
```

Comment: the condition given is that one must use the StackMachine

Comment: Where exactly is the validation happening?

Comment: how do i get to push() the user prompted String into the StackMachine and print the string character by character once it is validated by the  StackMachine

Comment: the StackMachine validates the Prompted String from user and checks if it is valid, according to the SM{ } rules that are defined in the StackMachine class or printRules() function..  all am needed is to write code that prompts String from user then push() the string to the machine then request the machine to print the reversed string from the stack and finally check if the string is a palindrome

Comment: A list can act as a LIFO (last in first out) structure, otherwise called a stack. Look at `list.append()` for pushing things (including characters) to the end of a list (link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). You can reverse a string, `text` as follows: `text[::-1]`. This is called slicing. More info on slicing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations.

Comment: Thank you i really need the whole code to work by printing if a given string is a palindrome or not as the final output of the whole code....yes, the StackMachine part included